# How can I get a new / non-technical user to verify my GnuPG / PGP signed email?

Tags: security, encryption, gnupg, pgp, public-key-encryption

I'm looking for a web front-end or some easy way to get a user who's never been exposed to cryptography / digital signatures etc. to simply copy/paste my GPG signed (not encrypted) email and specify whether that email/text has been correctly signed - meaning contents are untampered and from me - the sender.

Ideally, it would be able to pull my public key off a key server in order to verify or allow a user to upload the key along with the signed text for verification.

Basically - how would I be able to convince an ordinary user that the email sent is indeed from me.

**UPDATE:** I found something similar [here](https://www.hushtools.com/), but apparently it only works for users who've signed up for HushMail.

Comment: thats the main reason why crypto is not (yet) deployed among non-techies :)

Comment: @akira, well not when using PGP maybe. [S/MIME signed email](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME) is [handled fine](http://i.imgur.com/bfElS.png) by sane email clients.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [enigmail](http://enigmail.mozdev.org/home/index.php.html) Thunderbird extension.

It "just works" and shows you a little icon and offers you to verify signatures, import public keys, sign them, etc... No cut & paste involved.

Comment: I personally already use Enigmail as well as GPGShell. Both work exceedingly well. However, getting an ordinary user to switch from what is undoubtedly the majority interface (webmail) to a client isn't practical. I'm looking for some way to let a total n00b click one or two links and know whether or not the message was tampered with / originated from me.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried [FireGPG](http://getfiregpg.org) yet, but it should do what you had in mind. Unfortunately, it's discontinued, but maybe the latest version fits your needs.

Comment: i have tried it, but it's only meant for the Firefox browser.